# Are there any types of electrical faults that might exist in the landscaping or underground wiring that would not trip a gfci breaker at the panel?

Tags: electrical, wiring, gfci, pool

Are there any types of electrical faults that might exist in the landscaping or underground wiring that would not trip a gfci breaker at the pool panel?  Are there cases that a gfci would fail or not trip and continue to allow current on that circuit? In the case of swimming pool lighting and equipment, could there be a scenario that would draw current and create a dangerous condition? Does equipotential bonding around the pool prevent current from energizing the pool water?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

If the pool or any metal parts around it is bonded to neutral rather than earth ground, the GFCI would likely not trip and electrocute anyone between live and pool.

If there is a non-short conductive path between the pool and earth ground, the over-current breaker could possibly not trip under this kind of fault, and continue to expose the hazard.

Make sure the water and all metal around the pool are wired correctly and are only bonded to ground.

Make sure the neutral is wired to loads only (pump, lighting).

Make sure there is no connection between neutral and ground anywhere in the pool circuit: temporarily disconnect the neutral at the nearest junction box feeding the pool circuits, and check for the *absence* of continuity between neutral and ground.